# How to batch "gdal_merge" on Win7 in one command line command?

Tags: gdal

I want to create a mosaic of all tif files in a directory on windows 7.

How could I create a one-line command in the windows command line to loop through all tifs and merge them all together using gdal_merge.py?

I tried this;

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_merge.py -of GTiff %i mosaic.tif
```

but it gives me an error about mosaic not being a supported dataset name??

Comment: 1. create list using dir /b /s *.tif > list.txt          2. then gdal_merge.py --optfile list.txt

Comment: `gdal_merge.py -optfile list.txt` does not work using osgeo4w (i.e., under Windows). Throws a DLL Load failed exception

Comment: According to the userdocs for `gdal_merge`, a script exists to kludge `gdal_merge` wildcards into Windows gdal, but I haven't tried it. See http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalMerge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command line will try to merge mosaic.tif (as part of *.tif) with itself. Creating the mosaic in another folder would prevent that.

The correct syntax for batch processing is:

```
for %%N in (D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL50\*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba %%N D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL50\%%~nN.vrt
gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index.vrt NL50\*.vrt
pause
```

This should also work for gdal_merge.py, but I prefer to work with the vrt solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a batch for merging all the tif from a repository in a single tif file

```
gdal_merge.py -o out.tif *.tif
```

Comment: `gdal_merge.py -o out.tif *.tif` does not work using osgeo4w (i.e., under Windows). Throws a DLL Load failed exception

Comment: According to the userdocs for `gdal_merge`, a script exists to kludge `gdal_merge` wildcards into Windows gdal, but I haven't tried it. See http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalMerge