# Batch convert asc to TIFF

Tags: qgis, python, gdal-translate

I have 118 asc grid files, I need to convert them to TIFF. I've tried gdal translate but unfortunately GIS keeps crashing.
I was hoping I could use python to loop through all of them and save them.

Comment: what error are you seeing? `gdal_translate` on the command line is probably the easiest solution. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/88087/79

Comment: There is no error, I am not trying to merge them, the gis window just closes after a long time

Comment: Did you use export in batch mode within QGIS? This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, creating a windows batch file should be your best solution. You can try this script, just make sure the paths and your source crs are correct.

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

 SET mypath_in=G:\Input\Folder\
 SET mypath_out=G:\Output\Folder\

 FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B %mypath_in%*.asc') DO (

    SET infile=%%i
    SET outfile=!infile:.asc=.tif!
    

    "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20"\bin\gdal_translate.exe -co WORLDFILE=YES -a_srs EPSG:3044 -of GTIF "%mypath_in%!infile!" "%mypath_out%!outfile!"
    
    )
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried your script however, although it is reading the asc it is unable to convert them. I get the error "filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect. I have made sure that all the paths are correct and the crs too.

Comment: Fixed it thank you so much for this.

Comment: Is there a way to amend this to use grass r.stats on all those files too to get the statistics for each category? I need them to be saved to a csv which I will use to analyse further.

Comment: i m not familiar with r.stats - maybe you ask a new question for that?